# Multiple inheritance difference between Python 2.7 and 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance

I've already got that there is a difference between Python 2.7 and 3. implementing multiple inheritance, for example:

In Python 3.:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x2='', x3='', **kwargs):
        print kwargs
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.x2 = x2
        self.x3 = x3

class B:
    def __init__(self, x4='', x5='', **kwargs):
        print kwargs
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.x4 = x4
        self.x5 = x5

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, x1='', **kwargs):
        print kwargs
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.x1 = x1
```

And in Python 2.7:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x2='', x3='', **kwargs):
        print kwargs
        super(A, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.x2 = x2
        self.x3 = x3

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, x4='', x5='', **kwargs):
        print kwargs
        super(B, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.x4 = x4
        self.x5 = x5

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, x1='', **kwargs):
        print kwargs
        super(C, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.x1 = x1
```

Running the code:

```
C(x1='a',x2='b',x3='c',x4='d',x5='e',x6='f',x7='g')
```

In Python 3., I got:

```
{'x2': 'b', 'x3': 'c', 'x6': 'f', 'x7': 'g', 'x4': 'd', 'x5': 'e'}
{'x6': 'f', 'x7': 'g', 'x4': 'd', 'x5': 'e'}
{'x6': 'f', 'x7': 'g'}
```

But doing the same, Python 2.76 would result in an error too:

```
{'x2': 'b', 'x3': 'c', 'x6': 'f', 'x7': 'g', 'x4': 'd', 'x5': 'e'}
{'x6': 'f', 'x7': 'g', 'x4': 'd', 'x5': 'e'}
{'x6': 'f', 'x7': 'g'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
super(C, self).__init__(**kwargs)
super(A, self).__init__(**kwargs)
super(B, self).__init__(**kwargs)
TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
```

I noticed if I remove `super(B, self).__init__(**kwargs)` from Python 2.7 code, there won't be any error, as probably `class B` does not inherit from `class A`. Anybody knows how this work without any problem in Python 3? and any solution solving this problem in Python 2.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a sentinel object at the bottom of your inheritance tree that does *not* call `super().__init__()`:

```
class Sentinel(object):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        pass

class A(Sentinel):
    def __init__(self, x2='', x3='', **kwargs):
        super(A, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.x2 = x2
        self.x3 = x3

class B(Sentinel):
    def __init__(self, x4='', x5='', **kwargs):
        super(B, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.x4 = x4
        self.x5 = x5

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, x1='', **kwargs):
        super(C, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.x1 = x1
```

That way `Sentinel.__init__` is always called last and not `object.__init__`. This way you ensure that all your `__init__` methods accept the same arguments, always.

See [Raymond Hettinger's *`super()` considered super!* article](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) (or the [PyCon presentation based on it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo)).